# Activity below toolbar in navigation drawer in other activity

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I add Navigation drawer in my project by default navigation drawer activity, and  make item click with  go to new activity by extend , but when i add some text or button on the extended activity its go under the toolbar. so how can i solve this.

> This is the Navigation Activity that I can extend other new activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LevelActivity.class);
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_sql:
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_c:
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cpp:
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> This is the Xml file of new activity that i want to design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LevelActivity"
    >

<TextView
    android:text="This is problem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> This is the extended class

```
public class LevelActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //inflate your activity layout here!
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_level, null, false);
        drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
    }
}
```

[This is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udvqj.png)